# Is there any windows tool that do encryption and decryption for various algorithm

Tags: windows, cryptography

I am implementing various cryptography algorithms using windows crypto API. I need to verify whether my implementation is right or not. So Is there any such tool demonstrate various cryptography algorithms on windows?

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to implement cryptographic algorithms yourself, because it has almost certainly been done already, and the existing implementations perform better and have fewer timing vulnerabilities and such. That said, you should find test vectors in the relevant standards documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code accompanying the book .NET Security and Cryptography by Thorsteinson and Ganesh can be downloaded from http://objectinnovations.com/Library/Books/NetSecurity/index.html. It contains small programs showing the input/output when using different .NET crypto APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool named CryptoCalc, download link http://tools.pediy.com/Cryptography/calculator/CryptoCalc/christal_cryptotool12.zip